# Can't write correct filepath for the file that could be read from sepatare jobs

Tags: maven, jenkins, filepath, jobs

I use maven project and run it using Jenkins
Have problem with filepath: I write some info from one job to the file that is in the root directory of the project. Then I run another job and I need to take the info from that created file. But I can't get it, file, opened from the second job is empty.
Please help me to fix this problem
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The workspace directory for a Jenkins job is ephemeral, i.e. it gets deleted and rewritten when you run a new build of the job.  If you want to save a file from one job for consumption by another, use Jenkins' artifact archiving feature; here's a [blog post that explains everything](http://zeroturnaround.com/labs/jenkins-protip-artifact-propagation/).

Comment: Thanks! This is what I need. But I can't find where is the Pre-Actions to set the 'copy-from'... Maybe this is another version of Jenkins...

Comment: You need to install the Copy Artifact plugin - https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Copy+Artifact+Plugin